# Swift - Different Storyboards VS Universal

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, ipad, segue

I am dealing with quite a conceptional problem.

In my "universal" app i have a "table-view-controller" with a list of records which segue´s to a "view-controller".

On iPad Version of this app it behaves exactly like on the iPhone.

What i wanted to implement on iPad Version:

One View with "table-view-controller" on the left side and "view-controller" on the right side.

And when users selects a record from "table-view-controller" on the left side, this record is loaded directly in the "view-controller" on the right side.

Should i create a different storyboard to achieve this or create some:

```
if (iPhone) {
    // iPhone
    // do this
} else {
    // iPad
    // do this
}
```

conditions directly in code?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Take a look at size classes, I find them very handy https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are wanting is a "master-detail" interface.

This is what `UISplitViewController` is made for. And as of iOS 8, is available on both iPhone and iPad, thus you can have 1 setup (storyboard) that works as you'd expect on both idioms. Plus, it will help give good handling on things like iPhone 6 Plus, where going landscape may want to also have that side-by-side look and feel.

Take a look at `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer. Happy coding!